# When no price is required how to stop it displaying 0.00

Tags: price

Yesterday with some help from here I managed to work out configurable attributes so I could put a wine into my wine store and have the different year options for that wine with different prices depending on the year.

I then turned the price requirement off so when i load the first product I didn't have to have a price on it it would be like teh master product with teh drop down menu for the years available in that master product. http://www.cellar2door.com/index.php/reds/chile/montes-folly-syrah-38.html

Problem is that even though there is no price for teh master product it still displays as Rp0,000.

Is there a way to set the code so that if a price is not entered then nothing is displayed it is just blank?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure you have copy the `catalog/product/price.phtml` in your current theme.

Then you have to add one line before `<?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>` line

```
<?php if ($_product->getPrice() > 0) : ?>
    Whole file code
<?php endif; ?>
```

At last add `<?php endif; ?>`.

Comment: Thanks I did that but now I get an error on the page http://www.cellar2door.com/index.php/reds/chile/montes-folly-syrah-38.html

Comment: sorry ahve changed it back as teh whole site dissapeared with an error message for line 55 /home1/cellart1/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

Comment: i have update the code